# Does a constant current source add to existing current?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, current-source, kirchhoffs-laws

If I have a circuit where one branch contains a constant current source (e.g. 2A), does the current leading out of the current source equal the current leading into it (e.g. 4A) *plus* the current of the current source? That is, is the current leading out of the current source 2A+4A = **6A**?

Or does the current source simply ensure that the current along the entire branch is equal to its value, e.g. if the constant current source was 2A the current along the entire branch would be 2A.

EDIT: Here is a diagram; I'm asking if \$I_A = I_B = 5A\$ or if \$I_B = I_A + 5A\$. Apologies for my poor MS paint skills
[image: currentSource.png]

Comment: if you think of 2 loops with a shared resistor in the middle, and both loops were "pushing" a constant current into the resistor, the current through the resistor (the shared element only!) would be the sum of these currents. A resistor in each loop only would only show the current from that loop present through it.

Comment: Hi Kyran, I've added a diagram to clarify my question as I don't think I explained the source of my confusion properly.

Comment: What does Kirchoff's current law say about this?

Comment: It means that the current through the current generator is constant and at the rated value, in your diagram Ia=Ib=5A. This means that both the input and output currents are 5A. For any 2-terminal component, input current=output current.

Comment: @ThePhoton Assuming the constant current source is not "adding" current, then I think both \$I_A\$ and \$I_B\$ are 5A according to KCL. Is this interpretation that it is *not* adding current correct?

Comment: Kirchoff's current law says that it is impossible for any two-terminal element to "add" current the way you describe.

Comment: If you want to sum current like that, connect one end of the current source to ground, and the other end to the wire you want to "add" current to.

Comment: A current source does not "add" current to the path going through it. A current source keeps the current through it to the specified amount.

Comment: @rioraxe So would an inductor be an example of a current source then?

Comment: @NewDogOldTricks, no, the current through an inductor changes whenever there is a voltage difference between its terminals. The current through a (ideal) current source independent of the terminal voltage.

Comment: Series ideal voltage sources add. Parallel ideal voltage sources melt the universe with infinite current . Parallel ideal current sources add. Series ideal current sources zap the universe with infinite voltage. In the real world stuff happens but the universe usually doesn't melt.

Comment: Inductor is not a current source. Although in an instantaneous moment, an inductor can have the attribute of a current source. It can create confusion because some people then say an inductor behaves like a current source, but usually do not explicitly state that the behavior lasts for an instantaneous moment only.

Answer (score 1):

> IA=IB=5A

Yes. 
The current entering a node has to be same as current leaving the node. Even if another current source of 5 A is connected in series, the equivalent current will be 5 A. This is similar to two similar voltage sources connected in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Actual application of adding currents with current sources.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f82YXr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Current sources must be connected in // in order to work correctly and the load must be also //, otherwise they are fighting against each other. If connected in // then the currents sum up.